# Record audio of one minute

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am working with audio recording in Android.

I want to record audio maximum of 1 minute and if user ask to stop before one minute it should be stop.

I have record audio code and it works perfectly.

How can I set time duration it?

If solution is `thread.sleep` then it's ok. I do something like same:

```
   if (start) {
       startRecording();
       try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  } else {
    //What should do ? to stop thread this Thread.sleep(60000);

  callToStopRecording();
  }

     private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(path + mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error", "prepare() failed");
        }
        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
```

but at stop recoding button, what do I need to write?

Comment: can you show how you r recording...

Comment: i have added the code check it out

Comment: call the stopRecording method in stop recording button

Comment: I would start by taking a look on `Handler`. There you can find [postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) you can use to handle max 60 seconds recording. And [removeCallbacks(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to remove timer if button was pressed before 60 seconds time limit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this solution:

```
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(max_duration_ms);
```

The duation is in ms, so you have to use:

```
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(6000);
```